# Find Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.dll for SharePoint 2016 Environment

Tags: 2016, login, custom-login-page, trusted-identity-provider

I am developing custom login page webpart where I need reference `Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.dll`, but on my SharePoint 2016 environment I was unable to find that `dll`.

I have checked my assembly folder `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL` with no luck.

Can someone help me How can I find that dll for SharePoint 2016?

Comment: its in the `c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly` folder, exact location would somewhat like `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel\v4.0_15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c`

Comment: Thanks I found the dll on your given path. I request you to put your comment in answer so that I can mark it as answer. Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the GAC location changed after .NET Framework 4.0, the `Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.dll` is found in the below folder:

`c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly`

Exact location of the dll would be:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SharePo‌​int.IdentityModel\v4‌​.0_15.0.0.0__71e9bce‌​111e9429c`